# Component doesn't display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a `header.tsx` file with:

```
import React from "react";

export const Header = (title:any) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Then my `index.tsx` contains:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Header } from "./header"

ReactDOM.render(<Header title={"abc"} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

However, when I do `npm run dev`, the code will compile successfully, the localhost page is empty (blank). Instead I expected it to display "abc".

If I instead define `Header` in this fashion, it'll magically work:

```
export class Header extends React.Component<{ title: string }> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

So what's wrong with the way that `Header` was originally defined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a `string`, so no need to wrap it in an `object`.

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Header } from "./App";

// const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
// render(<App />, rootElement);

ReactDOM.render(<Header title="abc" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Also, `props` is an object. You can change your header code as below:

```
import React from "react";

export const Header = (props: { title: string }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-leavitt-uobbp?file=/src/App.tsx:0-151)

Also, recommend to use `any` as a last resort. You probably are not making best use of TS, if you use `any`. You know your data type so use `string`.

Answer (score 1):

`title` is a property in the props object. You can destructure and use like below,

```
 interface HeaderConfig {
  title: string
}

export const Header = ({ title }: HeaderConfig) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-moser-d4ss4?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I get the typescript error `TS7031: Binding element 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using props wrong way. Props of Header is an object. You can use destructure object to fix your issue:

```
export const Header = ({title} : {title: string}) => {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export const Header = (props:any) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        </div>
    )
};
```